# Simple DQN example - what to specify in config such that model params and results are printed out?

Tags: ray

I want to print params and results after running DQN or DDPG model. I triggered the model in jupyter notebook as following.

Defined the config and object and called training. as following:

But this did not print the model params and results. Please clarify how to print these?

Ubuntu EC2 instance
Jupyter notebook
DQN on cart pole example. 
Also want to do off policy training with my custom experiences dataset for my problem setting (online e-commerce data)

```
config_dict = {"evaluation_num_episodes":4,"num_workers": 10, "sample_batch_size": 200, 
               "train_batch_size": 200, "output": "outputdir", "gamma": 0.99, 
               "horizon": None,  
               "input": "sampler", 
               "optimizer_class": "SyncReplayOptimizer", "optimizer": {"prioritized_replay":True}, 
               "input_evaluation": ["is", "wis"], "callbacks": {"on_train_result": on_train_result},
               "ignore_worker_failures":True}


trainer = dqn.DQNAgent(config=config, env="CartPole-v0")

for epi in range(2):
    result = trainer.train()
    print(pretty_print(result))
    if epi %1000 ==0:
        checkpoint = trainer.save()
        print("checkpoint saved at", checkpoint)
```

A folder with model params and results json

Answer (score 0):

The results can be found in the ~/ray_results directory. The config will be in the params.json file, and the results in results.json. TensorBoard event files will also be written, and you can visualize the results with tensorboard --logdir=~/ray_results.

There's more info here: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-training.html#getting-started

Btw for offline batch RL, the documentation is this page: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-offline.html